# Sending an email with C# in windows 8.1 and VS2013

Tags: c#, email

I have been trying for a while now to send an email with C# on my windows 8.1 pc but this error keeps coming up

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Error in processing. The server response was: Request action aborted on MFE proxy, SMTP server is not available.

Please note that I have used the same exact code on my former pc without any problems. Also, I have turned off my firewall and antivirus without any success.

Below is the code I am using

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage {From = new MailAddress("mailfrom@gmail.com", "Oluwafemi")};
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("mailto@gmail.com"));
mail.Body = "body";
mail.Subject = "test";
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtpClient.Port = 587;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mailfrom@gmail.com", "password");
smtpClient.Send(mail);    
Console.WriteLine("sent");
```

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ran into this issue due to domain configurations... are you trying to send to/from gmail addresses using gmail's smtp?

If you aren't able to work around it, have you considered using a service like Mandrill.com or Mailgun.org.  They are both very permissive with their daily email quotas and very reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I think mandrill.com is the way to go. I am still having problems with sending attachments though.

Comment: What exactly is your issue with attachments

Answer (score 0):

Try changing following lines

```
smtpClient.Port = 587;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
```

to

```
smtpClient.Port = 465;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using on windows 8.1 and is **working** for me is,

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
    Port = 587,
    EnableSsl = true,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword)
};
```